# Java improve the performance of concatenating Strings in a loop

Tags: java, string, loops, concatenation

I'm writing a function with Java which can be simplified as following:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(50);
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
for(some condition){
   s.setLength(0);
   s.append("...").append("...").append("...").append("...");//add several strings to s
   q.add(s.toString());
}
```

I save those strings in the queue q, and if the size of the queue is bigger than a value, it will write q to a database. However it becomes slow especially when the times of loop is huge(millions). I assume that is because the concatenation takes a large amount of time. So is there any better way to do the concatenation? Thanks in advance for your help!

Update:
I want to use the same StringBuilder to create strings so each time I use `s.setLength(0)` to reset it at the beginning of each loop. These strings are the information of new nodes, such as its ID and some properties, so I need to retrieve these information by calling some functions and append them to the string `s`. The idea behind it is when the queue reaches to a specific size, I pop the information from this queue to create nodes to the Neo4j databases, since it will cost more if I use one transaction for every new node.

Comment: Why not create that string just once? It's always the same.

Comment: So you push each string into your queue and when you reach a certain queue size you append all elements in the queue, drain it to the string builder (concat to one string) and write that value to a database?

Comment: it would perhaps help if you pasted the actual code from where those strings you're appending to are coming from.

also why s.setLength(0) at the start of the loop, perhaps you can calculate the size of the buffer in advance and avoid recalculation as you append

Comment: @akuzminykh that's because these strings are the information of new nodes and their properties, and I need to get those information one by one by calling some functions.

Comment: Agreed with @Gubatron - use large enough (or only linked list)

Comment: One minimal optimization would be increasing the capacity(constructor parameter of `StringBuilder`) if you are sure initial capacity is probably more that 50!

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 yess that's what I want to implement

Comment: @tashkhisi I tried to print out the length by s.length() and the maximum value is 41 so I assume 50 is enough?

Comment: @Gubatron Thanks for your reply! I just updated my question by explaining what those strings are and because the information of each node is different, each time it's creating a new string without duplication. I'm not sure if I get your answer correctly.:)

Comment: You should use an ArrayBlockingQueue (thread safe) and thread the database operations in a scheduled service or a manually triggered service. I can't see your string builder being the slow point here.

Comment: @BrandNewStory I am not sure that string concatenation is the problem here - it takes me <400ms to concatenate 1e7 strings (including the same amout of String.valueOf(int))

Comment: @RandomCoder_01 Thank you! I will check the performance of other parts of the code instead of concatenation.

Comment: @Antoniossss Thank you! I will check the performance of other parts of the code instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling functions to get the strings then the fastest way is to not use the `StringBuilder` at all. Instead, use `concat()` function which is the best when looking performance-wise.

Here is an example:

```java
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
for(any condition){
  q.add(getStringOne().concat(getStringTwo()).concat(getStringThree()));
}
```

**Update**: So, after a comment that Builder is better than concat in this case. I ran some tests. `StringBuilder` takes more than 2X time when compared to `concat()`. And this is because we are not using the loop to create a single string but a new string with every iteration.

Here is the repl which I used to perform test: https://repl.it/@ankitbeniwal/StringBuilderVersusStringConcat

Comment: Builder is faster.

Comment: @Antoniossss It's no doubt that we should use ```StringBuilder``` when we work with loops. But in this case, We are creating a new string with every iteration. Can you throw some light?

Comment: And I think that this is exact reason why this is simply slower - because of creating (here) 3 different strings instead of appending to the one in each iteration (not one). I did small benchmark as I was curious of the results. I can share the code later on after ill get back from work. (in the meantime you can compare it yourself)